# Unable to display list item inline

Tags: css, inline

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/4kSpz/

Each `li` is shown inline, but for some reason the `<dl><dt>` is not inline.

What extra css do I need to include to move the `<dl><dt>` item inline with the other list items?

Comment: That CSS file is huge, maybe you could trim that down to the relevant css and place it within the fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.dselector dt` and `.dselector dt a span` you are using `display: block`.

You can change this to `display: inline-block` to keep it inline and display as block. Or if you want to support IE7 you can use `float: left`; just remember to clear your floats.

**Using `inline-block`: http://jsfiddle.net/4kSpz/2/**

**Using `float: left` : http://jsfiddle.net/4kSpz/3/**